# How can i iterate over elastic search results using angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, elasticsearch

In my dashboard application am using elastic search to retrieve data, which retrieves data fine. Now i need to iterate over the data and get the result in the required way.

Here is my code,

```
routerApp.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, ejsResource) {

       var ejs = ejsResource('http://192.168.1.200:9200');

        var oQuery = ejs.QueryStringQuery().defaultField('Agent');

        var client = ejs.Request()
            .indices('nondomain_callrelatedinfo')
            .types('callrelatedinfos');

        $scope.search = function() {
            $scope.results = client
                .query(oQuery.query($scope.queryTerm || '*'))
                .doSearch();
            console.log($scope.results);

        };

    });
```

I have added a console.log in the results and it reuturns something like this,
**Data:**

[image]

when i iterate over hits, it says cannot read property of "hits" undefined

```
$scope.dataRetrieved= $scope.results.value.hits;
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dataRetrieved.length; i++) {
                console.log($scope.dataRetrieved[i]);
             };
            };
```

Comment: Read it : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: There are so many ways to iterate over the data. like, foreach, _.each, etc..

Comment: @Ved ya i know that, but how can i get to that hits object inside the array?

Comment: ok.. Do you mean, how to iterate over data and get data some data inside another array..

Comment: @Ved yes, i have done in c#, not familiar with javascript

Comment: $scope.data = [];       $scope.data= $scope.results.value.hits;

Comment: It dint work @sandipon, TypeError: Cannot read property 'hits' of undefined

Comment: post data on 1 object inside yur array.. so that we can see the data..

Comment: @ved updated with the image

Comment: change $scope.results.value.hits; to $scope.results.value.hits.hits;

Comment: than check 
 
change $scope.results.value.hits; to $scope.results.value.hits.hits[0]; you must get data of first object..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69286/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-ved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Promise object that the `doSearch()` returns :

```
client
    .query(oQuery.query($scope.queryTerm || '*'))
    .doSearch().then(function (resp) { 
        var hits = resp.hits.hits; 
        // do whatever
    }, function (err) { 
        console.trace(err.message); 
    });
```

Knowing angular, if you want to bind the result to `$scope.result` maybe a `$timeout(function() {})` could also help.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

just nest your forEach:

```
angular.forEach(results, function(result, key) {
    angular.forEach(result, function(value, key) {
         this.push(key + ': ' + value);
    }, log);
}, log);
```

Comment: could you provide the exact way to get the result ? am getting an error undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0):

$scope.results.**hits.hits**;

```
$scope.dataRetrieved= $scope.results.hits.hits;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dataRetrieved.length; i++) {
            console.log($scope.dataRetrieved[i]);
         };
        };
```

the first hits is a object the second is your array. thats why the first hits has no property length

Comment: hits.hits – actual array of search results  see api

Comment: i dont get it, do i have to change anything

Comment: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_the_search_api.html   there is a object called hits and inside is a array called hits

Comment: exchange the code i provide with your code at the position

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69290/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-micha).